# Nested "IF" Statement

Tags: java, if-statement, nested, nested-loops

I need help find the test average and overall average using the nested "if" from my line of code. When I attempt to put it in a nested IF statement it doesn't run.

```
 System.out.print("Enter Test Scores : ");
    for(i=0; i<7; i++)
    {
        myList[i] = scan.nextInt();
        sum = sum + myList[i];
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
        totalPts += myList[i];
    }


    testAvg = totalPts/6;
    finalExam = myList[myList.length-1]; 
    finalAvg = (testAvg *.6) + (finalExam *.4);

    System.out.println("Final Avergae: " + finalAvg);
    System.out.println("Here are you grades: ");
    for (i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        System.out.println(myList[i]);
    }

    System.out.print("Your Grade is ");
    if (finalAvg>= (double)90)
    {
        System.out.print("A");
    }
    else if(finalAvg >= 80 && finalAvg < (double)90)
    {
        System.out.print("B");
    }
    else if(finalAvg >= 70 && finalAvg < (double)80)
    {
        System.out.print("C");
    }
    else if(finalAvg >= 60 && finalAvg > (double)70)
    {
        System.out.print("D");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("F");
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Show what you've tried and specify what exactly you need help with.

Comment: Also you appear to have an extra closing bracket; not sure if that is a copy-paste error, but that would stop it from running.

Comment: does my line of code follow the nested IF statement pattern ?

Comment: & its a copy-paste error

Comment: *it doesn't run.* What does this mean? Do you get an error?

Comment: It doesn't follow the nested IF statement structure so Zybooks isn't accepting it

Comment: What is Zybooks? And why would it need to accept anything?

Comment: It want the code but in a nested IF statement form ..... All i need is help formatting it in a nested IF statement

Comment: **What is Zybooks?** What does it say about nested if statements? Does it show an example? --- If it is a questionnaire at the end of a chapter, then perhaps if you (re)read the chapter, you'll see examples of what the site expects from "nested if statements".

Comment: It seems you are new here. Check on [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Also can you explain what is the error you are getting and more precisely where?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean like this?

```
if (finalAvg >= 90) {
    System.out.print("A");
} else {
    if (finalAvg >= 80) {
        System.out.print("B");
    } else {
        if (finalAvg >= 70) {
            System.out.print("C");
        } else {
            if (finalAvg >= 60) {
                System.out.print("D");
            } else {
                System.out.print("F");
            }
        }
    }
}
```